# Why is the water in the Waco Cable Park so green?

Tags: health, nature-and-wildlife, water-sports, texas

What makes the water in BSR Cable Park in Waco so green? The water is this color in most of their basins, I'm unsure if it's fed by natural springs or if it's all man made. Is the green water dangerous?

[image]

As far as I'm aware water this color usually means there is a bad algae  in the water that can make you sick. Yet there are so many people swimming in these waters. Do we need to watch out when accidentally swallowing water or something?

Comment: While blue-green algae is bad, it forms visible mats: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=blue-green+algae&tbm=isch

Comment: @CMaster thanks for the link, the water in these basins doesn't seem to have any visible mats.

Comment: Could be due to limestone or other finely ground rock particles in the water.  You see similar colors in borrow pits in Florida (where they dug out limestone to crush for roadbeds)

Comment: I think that would be an excellent answer to the question @Tom!

Comment: No, green water often means there's algae - but not necessarily bad ones.

Comment: @pnuts Seems obvious I already did, on multiple channels. They didn't answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They dye it to cover the color the soil it's built on would usually give the water:

"If there’s any drawback to BSR it’s that, because all the water attractions are man-made and dug into the clay soil of central Texas, the water would normally be an unpleasant gray color. So they dye it, either an unnaturally garish turquoise or a drab olive green."

Citation: http://www.expressnews.com/lifestyle/travel-outdoors/article/Slip-slidin-away-6472109.php

Comment: Your link to San Antonio Express-News is pay-walled. Any other freely accessible citations you know of?

Comment: @brhans Hmm, I didn't realize it was paywalled. Sorry, I can't some up with anything else. It does show up in [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:AKh-43PfOsUJ:www.expressnews.com/lifestyle/travel-outdoors/article/Slip-slidin-away-6472109.php+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) but I'm not sure how reliable that link will be